# Azure data factory: Implementing the SCD2 on txt files

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have flat files in adls source,
for full load we are adding 2 columns Insert and datatimestamp.
For change load we need to Lookup with full data, the data available in full should be taken as Updated and not available data as Insert and copy.

[image]

below is the approach I tried to work out, but i'm unable to perform.

Can any one help me on this.
Thanks you and waiting for quick response.

Comment: Using only Adf Activities

Comment: We have complete examples of implementing SCDs and SCD templates in the pipeline gallery

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature to update the existing flat file using the Azure data factory sink is not supported. You have to create a new flat file.

You can also use data flow activity to read full and incremental data and load to a new file in sink transformation.